# ZF3: Action and view doesn't found

Tags: php, zend-framework3, zend-framework-routing

In my application I have created a second action in a controller. When I call the application with the url http://local.domain I've got the correct page so it's called the correct controller. But If I want to make this call http://local.domain/liga-futbol-1 it doesn't work and I've got this error:

> A 404 error occurred Page not found. The requested URL could not be
>   matched by routing.
>
> No Exception available

**IndexController.php**

```
namespace Stats\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController {
    public function indexAction()
    {
        //This action serves the page
        return [];
    }

    public function ligaFubtol1Action(){

        return [];
    } }
```

**module.config.php**

```
namespace Stats;

use Zend\Router\Http\Segment;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\InvokableFactory;

return [
    'controllers' => [
        'factories' => [
            Controller\IndexController::class => InvokableFactory::class,
        ],
    ],
    'router' => [
        'routes' => [
            'home' => [
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => [
                    // This works!!! => http://local.domain
                    'route'    => '/',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller'    => Controller\IndexController::class,
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ],
                ],
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => [
                    // This doesn't work!!! http://local.domain/liga-futbol-1
                    'liga-futbol-1' =>  [
                        'type'  =>  Segment::class,
                        'options'   =>  [
                            'route' =>  '/liga-futbol-1',
                            'defaults'  =>  [
                                'controller'    => Controller\IndexController::class,
                                'action'        =>  'ligaFutbol1'
                            ],
                        ],
                        'may_terminate' =>  true,
                        'child_routes'  =>  [
                        ],
                    ],                    
                ],
            ],       
        ],
    ],
    'view_manager' => [
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => [
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
            'stats/index/index'       => __DIR__ . '/../view/stats/index/index.phtml',
            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        ],
        'template_path_stack' => [
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ],
        /*
         * Con este array de parámetros permitimos enviar datos y no mostrar vista
         */
        'strategies' => [
            'ViewJsonStrategy',
        ],           
    ],
];
```

**Directories:**

[image]

I have checked my cache in "/dir_project/data/cache" and there is nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the `route` option of the `home` route: it’s set to `/`. The `liga-futbol-1` route is a child route of the `home` route, so its URL is a “sum” of:

- `home` URL: `/`
- `liga-futbol-1` URL: `/liga-futbol-1`

In result: `//liga-futbol-1` is the URL of the `home/liga-futbol-1` route.

If you want just something like `/liga-futbol-1`, there are two solutions:

1. Make the `liga-futbol-1` route independent of the `home` route (i.e. not its child):

   ```
   'routes' => [
       'home' => [
           'type' => Literal::class,
           'options' => [
               'route' => '/',
               'defaults' => [
                   'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                   'action'     => 'index'
               ]
           ]
       ],
       'liga-futbol-1' => [
           'type' =>  Segment::class,
           'options' =>  [
               'route' => '/liga-futbol-1',
               'defaults' =>  [
                   'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                   'action'     => 'ligaFutbol1'
               ]
           ]
       ]
   ]
   ```
2. Remove `/` from the beginning of `liga-futbol-1`’s `route` option:

   ```
   'liga-futbol-1' =>  [
       'type' =>  Segment::class,
       'options' => [
           'route' => 'liga-futbol-1',
               'defaults' => [
                   'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                   'action'     => 'ligaFutbol1'
               ]
           ]
       ]
   ```